# why Image numpy array transpose and its inverse change color channel?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I just transpose the image and inverser the transpose Image color channel don't change as here

```
test = rgb.transpose(2,0,1)
test2 = test.transpose(1,2,0)
```

But when I add them in slides array and do the same procedure the color change

```
Train_x = np.zeros((1,4,x,x))
Train_x[0,0:3,:,:] = rgb.transpose(2,0,1)
s = Train_x[0,0:3,:,:]
s = s.transpose(1,2,0)
```

I tested their values they have exactly the same values. it is just when I plot them together using matplotlib they have different color

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just to cast the image into uint8 before giving it to matplotlib

```
astype(np.uint8)
```

because of this function

```
if A.dtype != np.uint8:
    A = (255*A).astype(np.uint8)
```